# Entity Framework Post method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables(Testresult & SampleCollection) linked to each other in a database. I have created a Post controller in entity framework that is saving data to both tables at the same time. But there is a particular condition that should be applied in saving data to both tables. I have condition A, condition B, condition C and condition D:

Condition A is the following screenshot:

```
[
  {
    "TestResult": {
      "iOutletStorageId": 50061,
      "dLastDeliveryDate": "2016-9-14",
      "szMarkingCertificate": "Tank 1: Mark Cert",
      "iFirstResultId": "1",
      "iSecondResultId": "2",
      "szFirstResultRemark": "Tank 1: First Result Remarks",
      "szSecondResultRemark": "Tank 1: Second Result Remarks 2",
      "szSiteVisitNo": "SVN01",
      "dTransdate": "2016-9-20 10:4:10.754",
      "iOutletId": 756
    },
    "MySampleCollections": {
      "iPPMSTestResultId": 0,
      "szZonalLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No Zonal",
      "szZonalSampleQty": "275",
      "szZonalSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. Zonal",
      "szCLabLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No C-Lab",
      "szCLabSampleQty": "275",
      "szCLabSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. C-Lab",
      "szGSALabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No GSA",
      "szGSASampleQty": "275",
      "szGSASerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. GSA",
      "szOutletLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No Outlet",
      "szOutletSampleQty": "275",
      "szOutletSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. Outlet",
      "szOutletSampleRecievedBy": "Tank 1:  Sample Received By Outlet",
      "szRetentionLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No Retention",
      "szRetentionSampleQty": "275",
      "szRetentionSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. Retention"
    }
  }
]
```

Condition B is the following screenshot:

```
[
   {
    "TestResult": {
      "iOutletStorageId": 50062,
      "dLastDeliveryDate": "2016-9-14",
      "szMarkingCertificate": "Tank 2: Cert #",
      "iFirstResultId": "1",
      "iSecondResultId": "2",
      "szFirstResultRemark": "Tank 2: First test Remarks",
      "szSecondResultRemark": "Tank 2: Second Test Remarks",
      "szSiteVisitNo": "SVN02",
      "dTransdate": "2016-9-20 10:4:10.754",
      "iOutletId": 756
    },
    "MySampleCollections": {
      "iPPMSTestResultId": 0,
      "szZonalLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No Zonal",
      "szZonalSampleQty": "275",
      "szZonalSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. Zonal",
      "szCLabLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No C-Lab",
      "szCLabSampleQty": "275",
      "szCLabSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. C-Lab",
      "szGSALabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No GSA",
      "szGSASampleQty": "275",
      "szGSASerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. GSA",
      "szOutletLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No Outlet",
      "szOutletSampleQty": "275",
      "szOutletSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. Outlet",
      "szOutletSampleRecievedBy": "Tank 1:  Sample Received By Outlet",
      "szRetentionLabelNumber": "Tank 1: Sample Lbl No Retention",
      "szRetentionSampleQty": "275",
      "szRetentionSerialNumber": "Tank 1: Seal No. Retention"
    }
  }
]
```

Condition C is the following screenshot:

```
[
   {
    "TestResult": {
      "iOutletStorageId": 50063,
      "dLastDeliveryDate": "2016-9-14",
      "szMarkingCertificate": "Tank 2: Cert #",
      "iFirstResultId": "1",
      "iSecondResultId": "2",
      "szFirstResultRemark": "Tank 2: First test Remarks",
      "szSecondResultRemark": "Tank 2: Second Test Remarks",
      "szSiteVisitNo": "SVN02",
      "dTransdate": "2016-9-20 10:4:10.754",
      "iOutletId": 756
    },
    "MySampleCollections": {
      "iPPMSTestResultId": 0,
      "szZonalLabelNumber": "",
      "szZonalSampleQty": "",
      "szZonalSerialNumber": "",
      "szCLabLabelNumber": "",
      "szCLabSampleQty": "",
      "szCLabSerialNumber": "",
      "szGSALabelNumber": "",
      "szGSASampleQty": "",
      "szGSASerialNumber": "",
      "szOutletLabelNumber": "",
      "szOutletSampleQty": "",
      "szOutletSerialNumber": "",
      "szOutletSampleRecievedBy": "",
      "szRetentionLabelNumber": "",
      "szRetentionSampleQty": "",
      "szRetentionSerialNumber": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Condition D is the following screenshot:

```
[
   {
    "TestResult": {
      "iOutletStorageId": 50063,
      "dLastDeliveryDate": "2016-9-14",
      "szMarkingCertificate": "Tank 2: Cert #",
      "iFirstResultId": "1",
      "iSecondResultId": "2",
      "szFirstResultRemark": "Tank 2: First test Remarks",
      "szSecondResultRemark": "Tank 2: Second Test Remarks",
      "szSiteVisitNo": "SVN02",
      "dTransdate": "2016-9-20 10:4:10.754",
      "iOutletId": 756
    }
  }
]
```

Now i want to be saving two rows or more than a row at time.

When i pass condition A & B, It's saving right to the database
When i pass condition A & C, It's saving right to the database
When i pass condition A & D, I am getting an error.

The idea is that, the second table will get its ID from the first table.

And here is my code:

```
public int PostTestResultObj(List<TestAndSampleResult> testandsampleresult)
        {
            long testResultId = 0;
            if (testandsampleresult != null)
                foreach (TestAndSampleResult orderdet in testandsampleresult)
                {
                    mdlTestResult NewTestResult = new mdlTestResult
                    {
                        iOutletStorageId = orderdet.TestResult.iOutletStorageId,
                        dLastDeliveryDate = orderdet.TestResult.dLastDeliveryDate,
                        szMarkingCertificate = orderdet.TestResult.szMarkingCertificate,
                        iFirstResultId = orderdet.TestResult.iFirstResultId,
                        iSecondResultId = orderdet.TestResult.iSecondResultId,
                        szFirstResultRemark = orderdet.TestResult.szFirstResultRemark,
                        szSecondResultRemark = orderdet.TestResult.szSecondResultRemark,
                        szSiteVisitNo = orderdet.TestResult.szSiteVisitNo,
                        dTransdate = orderdet.TestResult.dTransdate,
                        iOutletId = orderdet.TestResult.iOutletId
                    };
                SampleCollections newsamplecollectionmodel = new SampleCollections
                {
                    szZonalLabelNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szZonalLabelNumber,
                    szZonalSampleQty = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szZonalSampleQty,
                    szZonalSerialNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szZonalSerialNumber,
                    szCLabLabelNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szCLabLabelNumber,
                    szCLabSampleQty = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szCLabSampleQty,
                    szCLabSerialNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szCLabSerialNumber,
                    szGSALabelNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szGSALabelNumber,
                    szGSASampleQty = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szGSASampleQty,
                    szGSASerialNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szGSASerialNumber,
                    szOutletLabelNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szOutletLabelNumber,
                    szOutletSampleQty = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szOutletSampleQty,
                    szOutletSerialNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szOutletSerialNumber,
                    szOutletSampleRecievedBy = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szOutletSampleRecievedBy,
                    szRetentionLabelNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szRetentionLabelNumber,
                    szRetentionSampleQty = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szRetentionSampleQty,
                    szRetentionSerialNumber = orderdet.MySampleCollections.szRetentionSerialNumber
                };

                DataTable mydtTransReslt = Uow.tresult.GetTestResultNo(NewTestResult.iOutletStorageId,
                                            NewTestResult.dLastDeliveryDate, NewTestResult.szMarkingCertificate,
                                            NewTestResult.iFirstResultId, NewTestResult.iSecondResultId,
                                            NewTestResult.szFirstResultRemark, NewTestResult.szSecondResultRemark,
                                            NewTestResult.szSiteVisitNo, NewTestResult.dTransdate, NewTestResult.iOutletId);

                if (mydtTransReslt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    testResultId = Convert.ToInt32(mydtTransReslt.Rows[0]["NewPPMSTestResult"]);
                }

                if (testResultId > 0)
                {
                    long samples = Uow.spleCollections.GetSampleCollectionsNo(testResultId,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szZonalLabelNumber,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szZonalSampleQty, 
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szZonalSerialNumber,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szCLabLabelNumber, 
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szCLabSampleQty,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szCLabSerialNumber, 
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szGSALabelNumber,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szGSASampleQty, 
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szGSASerialNumber,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szOutletLabelNumber, 
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szOutletSampleQty,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szOutletSerialNumber,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szOutletSampleRecievedBy,
                            DateTime.UtcNow, 
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szRetentionLabelNumber,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szRetentionSampleQty,
                            newsamplecollectionmodel.szRetentionSerialNumber);
                }
                else
                {
                    mydtTransReslt.Columns.Add("Exception", typeof (string));
                    mydtTransReslt.Rows.Add("Sorry!!! Transaction Failed");
                }
            }
        return 1;
    }
```

Is it possible for me to pass both condition A & D without getting any error.
If possible, please how?
Thanks, Somad

Comment: Site note: look into an object mapper like Automapper because it would clean your code up considerably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to solve my question by putting the following code:

```
    public int PostTestResultObj(List<TestAndSampleResult> testandsampleresult)
    {
        long testResultId = 0;

        if (testandsampleresult != null)
            foreach (TestAndSampleResult orderdet in testandsampleresult)
            {
                if (orderdet.TestResult != null) //Making sure our results object is passing null
                {
                    mdlTestResult NewTestResult = new mdlTestResult
                    {
                        iOutletStorageId = orderdet.TestResult.iOutletStorageId,
                        dLastDeliveryDate = orderdet.TestResult.dLastDeliveryDate,
                        szMarkingCertificate = orderdet.TestResult.szMarkingCertificate,
                        iFirstResultId = orderdet.TestResult.iFirstResultId,
                        iSecondResultId = orderdet.TestResult.iSecondResultId,
                        szFirstResultRemark = orderdet.TestResult.szFirstResultRemark,
                        szSecondResultRemark = orderdet.TestResult.szSecondResultRemark,
                        szSiteVisitNo = orderdet.TestResult.szSiteVisitNo,
                        dTransdate = orderdet.TestResult.dTransdate,
                        iOutletId = orderdet.TestResult.iOutletId
                    };

                    //Persist the result
                    DataTable mydtTransReslt = Uow.tresult.GetTestResultNo(NewTestResult.iOutletStorageId,
                                                        NewTestResult.dLastDeliveryDate,
                                                        NewTestResult.szMarkingCertificate,
                                                        NewTestResult.iFirstResultId,
                                                        NewTestResult.iSecondResultId,
                                                        NewTestResult.szFirstResultRemark,
                                                        NewTestResult.szSecondResultRemark,
                                                        NewTestResult.szSiteVisitNo,
                                                        NewTestResult.dTransdate,
                                                        NewTestResult.iOutletId);

                    testResultId = 0;
                    if (mydtTransReslt.Rows.Count > 0) //Result inserted successfully
                    {
                        //Get the id of new result
                        testResultId = Convert.ToInt32(mydtTransReslt.Rows[0]["NewPPMSTestResult"]);

                        if (testResultId > 0)//Result insert was successful
                        {
                            if (orderdet.MySampleCollections != null && testResultId > 0) //Samples have been passed from client
                            {
                                foreach (SampleCollection Sample in orderdet.MySampleCollections)
                                {
                                    long samples = Uow.spleCollections.GetSampleCollectionsNo(testResultId,
                                                                        //newsamplecollectionmodel.iPPMSTestResultId,
                                                                        Sample.iSampleTypeId,
                                                                        Sample.szLabelNumber,
                                                                        Sample.iSampleQty,
                                                                        Sample.szSerialNumber,
                                                                        Sample.szRecievedBy);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mydtTransReslt.Columns.Add("Exception", typeof(string));
                            mydtTransReslt.Rows.Add("Sorry!!! Transaction Failed");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return 1;
    }
```

It's saving exactly the way I wanted it to be... 
Thanks